# declaring if an associated object is present - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I would like to adjust my view depending upon if an associated object is present. At the moment my view looks like so

```
<% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
  <h3 class="gallery-header">
    <%= t.name %>
    <span class="toggle"></span>
  </h3>
  <div class="gallery-row section-body">
    <ul class="team-gallery">
      <% t.gallery_images.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6).each do |g| %>
        <li>
          <%= link_to image_tag(g.photo.url(:gallery_small)), g.photo.url(:original), class: 'clb-photo' %>   
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
      <a href="galleries.html" class="button button-widget">View All</a>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Model associations are

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :gallery, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :gallery_images, :through => :gallery, dependent: :destroy
end

class GalleryImage
  belongs_to :gallery
end
```

So i though i could use a `if` block but my when there are no gallery_images assigned to a tournament I don't get the "Images to follow" text

```
<% @tournaments.each do |t| %>
  <h3 class="gallery-header">
    <%= t.name %>
    <span class="toggle"></span>
  </h3>
  <div class="gallery-row section-body">
    <% if t.gallery_images %>
    <ul class="team-gallery">
      <% t.gallery_images.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6).each do |g| %>
        <li>
          <%= link_to image_tag(g.photo.url(:gallery_small)), g.photo.url(:original), class: 'clb-photo' %>   
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
      <a href="galleries.html" class="button button-widget">View All</a>
    <% else %>
      <ul class="team-gallery">
       <li>IMAGES TO FOLLOW</li>
      </ul>
     <% end %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Im obviously looking at this in the wrong way, could anyone advise please

Thanks

Comment: I see an else part, but no `if`

Comment: it was there, i commented it, but ive removed the comment now, may be more visible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [.any?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F) command.

```
<div class="gallery-row section-body">
  <% if t.gallery_images.any? %> 
    # content
  <% else %>
    <ul class="team-gallery">
      <li>IMAGES TO FOLLOW</li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

t.gallery_images is always present, but it might be an empty array

you might (instead) want to write the test as

```
<% unless t.gallery_images.empty? %>
```

Comment: thanks, empty array, forgot that's what will be being returned